# I am not able to run a python script with CRON which tries to acces a .xlsx file in same directory

Tags: python, cron

```
***** /usr/local/bin/python /home/db2inst1/TicketAnalytics/newfinal.py > /tmp/listener.log 2>&1
```

in the script I gave the complete path to access the file:

```
file="/home/db2inst1/TicketAnalytics/example.xlsx"
print("open")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
```

nothing is getting printed in the log file

Comment: Probably because the code you posted is not printing anything to stdout nor stderr - the code posted doesn't include minimum example required to reproduce the problem of not writing to a file when expected to write

Comment: its just a part of the code... I tried to print to log file but nothing is getting printed. I mean the code is not running when I try to access the file.

Comment: Are you able to execute the script directly?

Comment: yea I am able to

Comment: Try giving full permission to the script chmod 777 newfinal.py

Comment: tried that not working still

Comment: Is there anything in syslog? There should be an error message saying why cronjob failed.

Comment: where should I see that

Comment: On Ubuntu that would be `/var/log/syslog` and you can grep for CRON like in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/56811/443644

Comment: no its not there

Comment: Another answer, old but may help. https://askubuntu.com/a/85610

Comment: the code which tries to access the .xlsx is only not running.. other parts of the code are running perfectly with cron.. and it works when I try to access a text file